# Mono ASP.Net Web Service CacheDuration hit ratio, under Linux

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching, mono, duration

I have developed an ASP.Net Web Service targeting Mono.  I have deployed it to an OpenSUSE 11.1 VM running Mono under Apache.

Is there a way to monitor the @OutputCache hit ratio for my ASP.Net app deployed for Mono under a Linux OS similar to the Windows Performance Monitor, for example?  This does not have to necessarily involve performance counters, but rather a method for getting the ratio.

This is related to WebMethod calls decorated with the CacheDuration attribute, not a custom data caching scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono has supported .NET "Performance Counters" since Mono 2.0, but AFAICT only three standard ASP.NET counters are currently implemented: Requests Queued, Requests Total, and Requests/sec. I imagine others, such as the cache hit ratio, would be pretty straightforward to implement.

You can inspect the performance counters using the performance counters API or the mperfmon GUI tool.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is a way to get the hit ratio from a Linux OS.  I'm a Windows guy, so I naturally think Performance Monitor.

Comment: Thanks for showing the mperfmon tool - this is what I was looking for.  
You say that "others, such as the cache hit ratio, would be pretty straightforward to implement" - do you have any resources on doing so?

Comment: AFAICT it's pretty much just a case of creating the counter objects and finding the right places to increment/decrement/alter their values, e.g. here's a patch that implemented 2 counters in about 10 lines each: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc?view=rev&revision=123835

If you need pointers about where to start, the best place to ask would be the mono-devel mailing list. You could also file a bug report on Mono's Bugzilla.

Beware that if you have ever viewed the code to Microsoft's System.Web, e.g. by using Reflector, you won't be able to contribute to (at least) that assembly in Mono.

Comment: FWIW, if you file feature requests in Bugzilla you'll increase the chance of someone else implementing them. This would also be a good place to get advice about how to implement things if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll take your suggestion and post onto Bugzilla.